# Small Traveling Salesman Problem instance

Tags: traveling-salesman, test-instances

The Traveling Salesman Problem is perhaps the most studied of all combinatorial optimization problems.  There has been a lot work in solving TSP instances to provable optimality.  [Concorde](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde.html) solves very large instances to provable optimality, with the largest solved having [85,900 points](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/pla85900/index.html).  There is a [100,000 city problem](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/data/ml/monalisa.html) that has not been solved to provable optimality.   But there are some [smaller instances](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/countries.html) not solved to optimality, with the smallest at 6732 cities.  Is this the smallest "difficult instance"?   Are there small TSPs that are hard for Concorde or other other optimization approaches to solve?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a paper of [Ahammed and Moscato](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-20525-5_1) on finding hard instances for Concorde using Lindenmeyer systems. They were able to find small instances with about 1500 cities that took (in 2011) more than 4 hours to solve.

One should probably add that "hard" always means "hard for some algorithm". So, for balance, here is a [paper of Kate Smith-Miles & van Hemert](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10472-011-9230-5) studying hardness for variants of the Kernighan-Lin algorithm.

For more on the pitfalls of "hard" versus "easy" in the context of SAT, there's an excellent [talk of Moshe Vardi](http://www.birs.ca/events/2014/5-day-workshops/14w5101/videos/watch/201401231116-Vardi.mp4) where he concludes that "the 'easy-hard-easy' picture is patently wrong".

Answer (score 8):

There is a paper by Papadimitriou and Steiglitz [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7487/ea033b1729fb7695841673ece0e4782fdb88.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjvkbn14triAhUkiOAKHfrnBE8QFjAQegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3914Eqq0wxHhc6vbw-c-gK) to construct instances, which are very hard for local searches to find optimal solution.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if LP+cut approaches can sort out those instances: the LP gives a global view but I would bet the LP fractions hedge the choices in each of the widgets.

Comment: I can test this by a Branch-and-Cut to evaluate the performance of exact methods on these type of instances, I let you know about this @Michael.

Answer (score 1):

[Hard to Solve Instances of the Euclidean Traveling Salesman Problem](https://www.or.uni-bonn.de/%7Ehougardy/HardTSPInstances.html) provides awhole class of hard to solve small instances for the planar Euclidean TSP; the are also downloadable instances.

Comment: Oh very cool.  This was known a year before I posed the question.  I wonder if there has been anything since 2018?